# python2.7 pip install tensorflow when installed Anaconda with python3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I had a large python 2.7 project which require tensorflow.  But I can not pip install it when I have  installed Anaconda with python3.5.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Given error:

Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\victo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.14.0)
s\victo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow) (3.1.1)
Collecting setuptools>=41.0.0 (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
..
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/86/095d2f7829badc207c893dd4ac767e871f6cd547145df797ea26baea4e2e/setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Found existing installation: setuptools 27.2.0
ERROR: Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\users\victo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth

Comment: I do not understand why you use Python 3.5 if your project is Python 2.7

Comment: unfortunately I have other projects require anaconda with python3.5.  I am looking for a solution that I can change between python 2.7 and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have both installations. Just install it in another folder, and run the anaconda version you need according to the project.

Comment: I think tensorflow can not be installed on python2.7 on anaconda.  Only vision above python 3.5 can.

Answer (score 0):

You should create different environments for different projects, which is a very basic function included in `conda`. `conda` is both a package manager and a environment manager.

[What's a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment)

> venv (for Python 3) and virtualenv (for Python 2) allow you to **manage separate package installations for different projects**. They essentially allow you to create a **“virtual” isolated Python installation** and install packages into that virtual installation. When you switch projects, you can simply create a new virtual environment and not have to worry about breaking the packages installed in the other environments. It is always recommended to use a virtual environment while developing Python applications.

Examples

```sh
# create an virtual environment named py2 with Python 2.7 installed
conda create -n py2 python=2.7

# another env named py3 with Python 3.7
conda create -n py3 python=3.7

# activate an env and install package into this very env
conda activate py3

# install packages with pip, or conda
pip install tensorflow
# or
conda install tensorflow

# exit the env
conda deactivate
```

**Tips**: After an env is activated, you can use `pip` or `conda` to install packages into it. But never use both of them within a virtual environment.

Extended Reading

- [get started with `conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)
- [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)